# Using Node and Socket.io I am trying to pass a simple array and I'm getting nothing. What did I miss?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I followed the [net tuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socket-io-and-expressjs/) to build a simple chat application with socket and node, and now I'm trying to extend the app to allow people to play a game I've written, so I want to let people list the games available, but I can't seem to pass even a simple test array from server to client.

I'll let the code speak for itself:

**Relevant Server Code:**

```
var games = ["test"];
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('message', { message: 'welcome to the chat' });
  socket.on('gameList', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit("games",games);
  });
  socket.on('send', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('message', data);
  });
});
```

**ClientSide:**

```
window.games = [];
$("#listGames").click(function(){
  socket.emit("gameList", function(data){
    window.games = data;
  })
})
```

So I console.log games before and after the button click, and it's always just an empty array, when in my head, it should contain the string `"test"`.

So where did I go wrong?

**Note:**
Added jQuery to the codebase even though the tutorial missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `socket.emit()` to attempt to receive data. That only sends data to the server. You need a `games` event handler on your client to handle the event accordingly.

```
window.games = [];

$("#listGames").click(function() {
  socket.emit('gameList');
});

socket.on('games', function (games) {
  window.games = games;
});
```

The event handler for `games` is what will fire when you execute `io.sockets.emit('games', games);` on the server side.

Also make sure to always pass an object as the response over Socket.IO. Change the server-side code from : `var games=[];` to `var games={'games':[]};` or something similar.

Comment: I also noticed that I can't pass the array, it has to be an object. Once I fixed both, I've got it working. Might be coincidence, but better for me anyway, now I have an object with available games.

Comment: edited your answer to include the change to serverside code. will accept as soon as it goes through. Feel free to change it if you want. Just wanted to accept the fix to both problems in one answer.

Comment: hi , is it secure to pass function from client to server??  how you see this solution on production?